# Setting a title and a UIBarButtonItem in WePopoverController

Tags: ios, uikit, popover

I am implementing a `WEPopoverController` and would like to set the title and put a button on top of the popover.  Is it possible to do that with this controller?

This is what I have so far.  I am loading `TableViewController` into the popup.
I tried to set `self.title=@"title";` in the tableviewcontroller's `viewdidload` but that didn't help.  I only see the tableview with borders inside.

I tried to create a tableview controller in storyboard and programmatically load into the popup but i couldn't resize it.  Plus i am not sure if that would be good programming practice.

This is how i load the popuptableview.  Would it be easier to use a UIViewController?  I don't really need the tableview.

```
PopUpTableViewController *popUpTable = [[PopUpTableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   // TestViewController *testView = [[TestViewController alloc]init];
    self.popoverSettingsController = [[WEPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUpTable];
    [self.popoverSettingsController presentPopoverFromRect:frame
                                                    inView:self.view 
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                  animated:YES];
```

I looked through the preference options but didn't see anything about title.  Would i have to resize the container?

Comment: I have looked into the classes but there is nothing like titleView or titleLabel for which we can set value. You may need to customize contentView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a navigation controller with your popUpTable as root view controller and then use the navigation controller as the content view controller for the pop over.

If the above is done, then your logic of self.title inside popUpTable and creating bar button item will work!